# What can be said about $f$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I faced this question in an interview yesterday.

> **QUESTION:** We have a function $f$ depending on three variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Now the gradient of $f$ is perpendicular at any point
>   $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, or in mathematical language , $$\vec r \cdot \nabla f
>  =0$$ Now what can be said about $f$ from this information?

I could not make out anything from this. And I failed to proceed since I did not know the relation between $x_1,x_2,x_3$. I was given the hint that I should consider the function $f(t\vec r)$ where $t$ is a scalar and differentiate it with respect to $t$. I calculated it as:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[f(t\vec r)\right]=f'(t\vec r) \vec r$$

I was still unable to make any interpretation. I was asked what the $f'$ thing meant. I said that it was a derivative but he asked me what it signified. But I had no clue.

Can anybody help me?

**P.S.** You can take $\vec r=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. The interviewer said nothing about this. So I think it will be that way only.

Comment: In the problem statement, is $\vec{r} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$?

Comment: @EliRose Yes, probably. The interviewer mentioned nothing about this. So it must be like that. I am putting this into the question.

Comment: The gradient is perpendicular to level curves

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculations are wrong. It should read as

$$\frac d{dt} f(tx_1, tx_2, tx_3) = \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_1} \frac { \partial (tx_1)}{\partial t} + \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_2} \frac { \partial (tx_2)}{\partial t} +
 \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_3} \frac { \partial (tx_3)}{\partial t} = \nabla f \cdot \vec r = 0$$

that is, if you fix a direction (fix $x_1, x_2, x_3$) your function is constant along that direction.

Hence, your function only depends on the angle (or the direction) of the point, not on the distance. That is

$$f(\vec r) = f(\vec r/a)$$

for every $a > 0$

Note that in general this is *not* constant.

It is constant if it is continuous at the origin: in this case, for every point $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ you can "go back" along the line connecting this point to $0$ (without changing value); and if $f$ is continuous at $0$, then it must be that $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f(0,0,0)$ for any $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

On the other hand if $f$ is not continuous (or not defined) in $0$, then you will have some sort of "sphere" that generates all the values of the function, and they can be different

Comment: It must be constant if $f$ is continuous at the origin. But if $f$ is only defined on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$, we have nonconstant differentiable such functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice point, thank you. I added it in :)

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you give a reference to such an example?

Comment: @mvw I don't know of a reference, but if you let $g$ be any differentiable function on the unit sphere and set $f(x) = g(x/\lVert x\rVert)$, then $f$ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ with $\langle \nabla f(x), x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$. And $\langle \nabla f(x),x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$ implies that $f$ is of that form. Since $f$ is constant on rays emanating from $0$, it's clear that $f$ can be continuously extended to the origin if and only if $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 4):

Update: My old proof had an error.

> Now the gradient of $f$ is perpendicular at any point
>   $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$,

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}
0 
= \grad f \cdot x 
= x_1 \partial_1 f + x_2 \partial_2 f + x_3 \partial_3 f \quad (1)
$$

This works if the gradient is zero, which would mean $f$ is constant.

But can there be a non-zero gradient?

Below is an image of the 2D case $h(x_1, x_2) = (x_1, x_2)$ (red arrows) and a possible orthogonal vector field (green arrows)
$g(x_1, x_2) = (-x_2, x_1)$, both arrow lengths reduced to $15\%$.

[image: 2D vector field] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOzJO.png), [Source](https://kevinmehall.net/p/equationexplorer/vectorfield.html#x*i%20+%20y*j%7C-y%20*i%20+%20x*j%7C%5B-100,100,-100,100%5D))

Problem: This field $g$ seems to have a non-zero curl and can not be a gradient field, as gradient fields have zero curl.

I would love to have a proof of this, that non-zero orthogonal vector fields to $h$ can not be gradient fields, but I have not found one yet.

The other argument is using the level curves:

The gradient is orthogonal to the level curves $f = \text{const}$, which would have the vectors $h(x) = x = r e_r$ as tangent vectors. So we would have curves
$$
r(t) = m t \quad (t \in \mathbb{R})
$$
for constant vectors $m$ where $f$ is constant.

However all those curves of same level intersect at the origin, so they must share the same value.

BTW the term $\frac{d}{dt}f(t x)$ at $t=0$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at the origin in $x$-direction
$$
D_x f(0) 
= f'_{0,x} = \left. \frac{d}{dt}f(0 + t x) \right\vert_{t=0}
= \left. \grad f \right\vert_0 \cdot x 
= \left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right\vert_0= 0
$$

Comment: I had this answer in my mind. But this looked like a trivial case. Can you make some rigorous proofs?

Comment: I had interpreted the question as: the gradient in a point $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is perpendicular to the vector $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. In general it's not constant

Comment: @mvw At any point, but $\nabla f$ is also calculated in $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. At least that is how I interpreted it, I doubt he meant "Take any two point $(x_1, x_2, x_3) $and $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$, then $\nabla f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \cdot (y_1, y_2, y_3) = 0$

Comment: Right, but then in general the function does not have to be constant (see my answer). It also appears to me that your proof is flawed, as you consider $g$ constant when you multiply it by the canonical base, and I can't see why that's correct

Comment: That statement seems to depend on the possibility that $f$ is not defined at the origin. The task says only that $f$ depends on three variables $x_i$. There is nothing said about any restriction of the kind $x \ne 0$. The gradient seems to be defined for any point as well, so I would assume it to be defined for the origin as well, I think it vanishes there, because all direction derivatives vanish. But I am not sure. The gradient indeed was mistakenly constant on the full space, so I dropped that proof attempt.